# using xpath in selenium.get.Text and selenium.click

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-rc

I have `<a href="/address_shops/">Адреса магазинов</a>` on page and want to store text, then click on this link and verify that the page where am I going to contains this text in headers. So I tried to find element by xpath, and selenium.getText get the right result, but selenium.click goes to another link. Where have I made a mistake? Thanks in advance!

```
    String m_1 = selenium.getText("xpath=html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/h4[1]");
    selenium.click("xpath=html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/h4[1]");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    assertTrue(selenium.getText("css=h3").contains(m_1));
```

page:http://www.svyaznoy.ru/map/

---

Resume:
using `xpath=//descendant::a[@href='/address_shops/'][2]` or `css=div.deff_one_column a[href='/address_shops/']` get right results

using `xpath=//a[@href='/address_shops/']` - Element is not currently visible
`xpath=//a[@href='/address_shops/'][2]` - Element not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, didn't notice page link. Css for second link can be something like that `css=div.deff_one_column a[href='/address_shops/']`

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing slash at the beginning of the expression. I am kind of surprised this got through at all - the first slash means "begin at root node".

Also, it is better to select the `<a>` element instead of the `<h>`. Sometimes it works, sometimes is misclicks, sometimes the click doesn't do anything at all. Try to be as concrete as you can be.

Try this one.

```
String m1 = selenium.getText("xpath=/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/h4/a");
selenium.click("xpath=/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/h4/a");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
// your variable is named m1, but m_1 was used here
assertTrue(selenium.getText("css=h3").contains(m1));
```

By the way, there are even better XPath expressions you could use. See [the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), it *really* is helpful. Just an example, this would work, too, and is much easier to write and read:

```
String m1 = selenium.getText("xpath=//a[@href='/address_shops/']");
selenium.click("xpath=//a[@href='/address_shops/']");
```

Comment: or even selenium.click("link=" + m1);

Comment: @Slanec "your variable is named m1, but m_1 was used here" - sorry, edit this post several times. actually I have m_1

Comment: @AlehDouhi I can't use this, because there are two links on this page, but I need to check the second one

Comment: looks like it's all wrong in my test, isn't? I had to check the second link on that page

Comment: then you can try `String m_1 = selenium.getText("xpath=//a[@href='/address_shops/'][2]");` and `selenium.click("xpath=//a[@href='/address_shops/'][2]");`. But I believe that it is possible to find your locator with css too

Comment: I tried to use this and got "Element not found". when I am using css (get it from IDE) I get the same, but sure there are two links /address_shops

Comment: Then your links have different parents I think. Try `//descendant::a[@href='/address_shops/'][2]`. You can also find any unique element near your second link and easy get link itself by css selector